# Is there an advanced javascript editor out there that will do things like 'go to definition' similar to Visual Studio?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ide, editor, intellisense

I have this JQuery/Javascript based project and the Visual Studio 2008 .JS file editor just isn't good enough, Notepad++ does better coloring and context highlighting but I am looking for an editor that will do more advanced things like auto-completion with my custom created objects and 'go to definition' style code navigation, for example.

Is there anything like this out there you could recommend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say check out vs2010 because it has a lot better support for javascript. Also if you really want to do some cool stuff check out resharper for visual studio as they are also adding support for javascript in their release. Makes my life a lot easier.

Comment: I can't upvote this enough.  VS2010+ReSharper is a pleasure to work in.  The JSEnhancements extension is also pretty nifty.

Answer (score 2):

The [Zeus](http://www.zeusedit.com) editor has an semi-automatic [ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) feature and it uses this tag information to drive it's *go to definition* and *auto complete* features.

Generally the *auto complete* works well enough for static languages but for dynamic languages like *Java Script* it really does not work very well.

But ctags does pick up things like Java Script classes and functions so the *go to definition* feature should still work.

Comment: Tried the demo, didn't do anything I wanted :/ clicking 'Go To Definition' never worked on my .JS file even though it contained the definitions for the objects and methods.

Comment: For the 'Go to Definition' to work you need to create a Project/Workspace containing the file. The way it works is the workspace automatically manages the ctags information for all the files in the workspace and the 'Go to Definition' uses this ctags information to do the navigation.

Answer (score 1):

"go to definition" is there for javascript in Visual Studio 2012 RC